# Vertically align to right of image no matter screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a Bootstrap row with two columns. I was wondering how to ensure that the text is always vertically aligned to the image even if the screen width decreases.

As seen in these pics, it's fine when the screen is wide enough but when it decreases in width the text alignment messes up:

[image: Wider screen result]

[image: Narrower screen result]

This is my code:

```css
.success img {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin: 0% 10% 10% 10%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 20%; 
}

.success h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  height: 20%; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature" height="20%" width="20%">
    <h4>Education</h4>
    <p>School...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people" height="20%" width="20%">
    <h4>Education</h4>
    <p>School...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I keep the text vertically aligned to its respective image?

Comment: Where is `.success`?

Comment: Set a width in % to both the divs? Also, depends on how you set the rest of your script if this will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try something like this. It use flex-box:
+ .row-eq-height: make two (or more) col(s) always have same height
+ .box-center: very helpful to center something even you dont have specific height

```
**CSS**
.box-center {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

**HTML**
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-md-4 row-eq-height">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 box-center">
            <div><h4>Education</h4>
            <p>School...</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 box-center">
            <div><h4>Education</h4>
            <p>School...</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.box-center {
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -ms-flex-align: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-md-4 row-eq-height">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 box-center">
            <div><h4>Education</h4>
            <p>School...</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 box-center">
            <div><h4>Education</h4>
            <p>School...</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```